# Transfer file from one machine to other using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I'm new to jmeter and trying to upload file from one system(linux eg 10.20.30.108 is my source) to other(eg10.20.30.107 is my destination)  using jmeter to perform load testing.
So can anyone suggest me the way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can install a plugin which adds [SSH Protocol Support](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler) to JMeter, as a result you will get [SSH Command](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command) sampler which you will be able to use to perform file transfers across Linux machines via [scp command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp)

You can install SSH Protocol Support plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter SSH Protocol Support]

Comment: CaN u please provide me a link where i can understand the various parameters of SSH parameter like what will be the hostname(source or destination) ogf which machine i nedd to give username and password and how to use scp command coz I'm not a superadmin of the machine can we use SSH SFTP for the same?

Comment: **Hostname**: `ip address or hostname of the "source" machine`. **Command**: `scp /path/to/source/file destination_username@destination_hostname:/path/to/destination/file`. See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) for details. And yes,  SSH SFTP might be easier to use in your case.